# Debugging GQL Queries

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I have been trying to run this query:

```
my_post = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Post where __key__ = KEY('Post', 1)")
self.render("showpost.html", my_post = my_post)
```

and my template `showpost.html` looks like this:

```
<div class="post">
  <h3 class="post-subject">{{ my_post.subject }}</h3>
  <div class="post-content">{{ my_post.content }}</div>
</div
```

Instead of getting the details of the Post of `id=1`  I'm getting a blank page. Although there exists a post with id=1 i'm not sure how to confirm if the GQLquery is actually returning something. Is there a way to check?
On trying the following:

```
my_post = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Post where subject = 'hello_world')
self.render("showpost.html", my_post = my_post)
```

I get the same issue (blank page), even though there is post who's subject is `hello_world`

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GqlQuery` is a class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass#GqlQuery).
Your code has created an instance of the `GqlQuery` class.
To return something from the datastore you need to use either of the following instance methods:

```
.fetch() # requires number of entities as first argument
.get()
```

Example:

```
my_query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Post WHERE subject = :subject", 
                       subject="hello_world")
my_post = my_query.get() # the magic happens here
self.render("showpost.html", my_post = my_post)
```

Answer (score 2):

Bernie is right in that you need to use `.fetch` or `.get` to actually retrieve results from the GqlQuery that you created, but for the first version, where you have a key or an id, you don't want to create a query at all. Rather, use the methods that are provided for using them directly.

If you have an id, use:

```
my_post = Post.get_by_id(id)
```

this will be much faster than using a query object.

If you have an entire key, use:

```
my_post = Post.get(key)
```

That is the fastest and most efficient way to get an entity out of the database.